# Convert DC generator to variable AC

Tags: power-supply, power, current, frequency, converter

Is there a way to convert a DC generator signal to AC and be able to control the frequency and current?

Ultimately, I would like to use this signal to measure the impedance of a battery.

Comment: It sounds more like you want a signal generator where you can control voltage and frequency. Alternately, find yourself a sinewave oscillator and amplify the signal to whatever level you want.

Comment: Not sure what the generic name is, but Danfoss produces VLT's. They convert mains supply to a different frequency and voltage, usually to drive a motor (like a modern elevator that you hardly feel accelerating). I bet some of brands support DC input too.

Comment: You can alternatively use a microcontroller and a [DAC](https://www.google.com/search?q=digital+to+analog+converter+chip&safe=active&gws_rd=ssl#q=digital+to+analog+converter+IC&safe=active) that is amplified or buffered by an op-amp. The program for generating a sinusoid isn't terrible difficult, but this solutions depends on the resolution you require.

Comment: Depends on the DC generator, car alternators for example generate AC which is then rectified, ditching the regulator pack gives you up to 120v AC, frequency determined by RPM of the spindle as with any AC generator. However, that's not exactly an easy one to keep nicely controlled for measurements purposes.

Comment: can you be more specific with your questions, it is too vague at the moment.

Comment: @jippie: the thing you are thinking of is a 'variable speed drive'. Also known as a VVVF drive (variable voltage, variable frequency drive) or a 'frequency converter'. They are basically a big switched mode power supply, feeding a DC bus, strapped to a big AC inverter circuit. Danfoss is one manufacturer, others are ABB, Vacon, and Siemens. We use them to drive big motors.

Answer (score 1):

> Ultimately, I would like to use this signal to measure the impedance
>   of a battery.

The simplest way is to load the battery with a known value power resistor and note the volt reduction on the battery terminals. That volt reduction is due to the impedance of the battery. Well I say impedance but it's the Effective Series resistance (ESR) of the battery and is the dominant factor in impedance.

OK, so there is a volt reduction due to current and that current is known - it's the voltage across the known-value power resistor. So you now have the volt reduction and the current - use ohms law and you get the impedance (ESR) of the battery.

If you want to go about this in a more convoluted way, buy or build an AC inverter BUT the results you get won't be any better.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possibilities and designs to get what you want. Look a little more in internet, there are very simple designs with astables or RC oscillators, with OP amplifiers or little more sophisticated with pwm ICs and filters). 
I would separate your question in to steps:

- step 1:**To get the AC output from DC**, [here](http://www.electroschematics.com/220/12v-dc-220v-ac-converter/) a link to a good example, using an astable multivibrator IC. You can change the output AC frequency changing the astable frequency with a potentiometer.
- step 2:**To get the current control**, you can add to the output of the step1 a specified IC for this propose like the [L200](http://www.circuitstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/l200.pdf) or the simplest way placing a power transistor with potentiometer to get the desire current output, like [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Adjustable-constant-current-source-4mA-to-3A/).

Depend on the characteristics of the battery you must adjust a little the design.